# StaggeredGridLayoutManager with Retrofit

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use StaggeredGridLayoutManager in a fragment (Fragment is part of a ViewPager), MY list of array is filled by json, using retrofit.  At the first time i open the fragment every think is ok, but when i forward to another activity and pres the back button my fragment does not show anymore the elements, it is empty.
I debugged and the json is parsed, the adapter is notyfied but the fragment is empty. If i close the app and open it again everything works at the start.

The code is:

```
  recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
    itemAnimator.setAddDuration(1000);
    itemAnimator.setRemoveDuration(1000);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);

    adapter = new OffersAdapter(getActivity(), offers);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Retrofit   onResponse `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

My activity is like the photo, when i click to the to the third fragment called "Oferta" everything is fine, than if i click the first fragment called "Vitrina" than click again third fragment, it is empty again, please if you can help with that too.. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setRetainInstance()` on your `Fragment` inside `onCreate()` method like this:

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }
```